# How do I get my PHP variable to echo inside my CSS stylesheet?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

OK, so I'm building a Wordpress theme that will allow my client to assign a colour to each category. However this is proving to be quite difficult when it comes to making the stylesheet read the code.

I'm using this code

```
.thumbnail-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: <?php echo $category_color; ?> ;
}
```

but for some reason the PHP isn't being noticed.

I've also placed the following code at the top of the stylesheet and changed the .css extension to .php

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>
```

**EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention. The variable is being defined by the category. Here's the code:**

```
<?php
            $category = get_the_category();
            $the_category_id = $category[0]->cat_ID;

            if(function_exists('rl_color')){
                $rl_category_color = rl_color($the_category_id);
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: where's the variable debing defined? YOU can't just suddenly start outputting a variable in a script without assigning something to it in the first place.

Comment: *"but for some reason the PHP isn't being noticed"* Meaning what? What actually happens? Is `<?php echo $category_color; ?>` literally shown on the page?

Comment: Where is $category_color being set?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-variables-to-your-css-files--net-2663 you can try this.

Comment: @DariusCarter please edit your question and add the code there, not in the comments.

Comment: What is the problem? background has no value? Don't you want to use inline css style?

Comment: @DerekBaxter Sorry, edited and added in the question.

Comment: @DariusCarter `$category_color` was not set in the code that you provided, try testing by doing an `if` statement and checking to see if the variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

multiple ways

one is Set .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .css
```

and echo the data in .css file.

Comment: You may want to reread this part of the question: *"I've also placed the following code at the top of the stylesheet and **changed the .css extension to .php**"*

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the file has a name with 'style' in it, and leave the extension as `.css`.

Then go to your `.htaccess` file and add this into it to force it to be executed:

```
<FilesMatch "^.*?style.*?$">
    SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: You may want to reread this part of the question: *"I've also placed the following code at the top of the stylesheet and **changed the .css extension to .php**"*

Comment: Yes, and it still didn't work for the OP. Leave it as `.css` and then it'll work with the above method.

Comment: Assuming that the server is properly configured, this code would fail in exactly the same way. The problem is happening with a file that presumably executes PHP code. This code does the same.

Comment: Although the server must be executing PHP correctly to some extent for Wordpress to run. This is an inherent and known problem with wordpress and this solution is known as a possible fix.

Answer (score -1):

It will work, assuming the structure is something like this and the file extension is php:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    $category_color="blue";
?>
.thumbnail-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: <?php echo $category_color; ?> ;
}
```

Check how you set the `$category_color`.

[There's a file on my server with the above contents](http://justachat.freevar.com/styles.php).